# How to create a nested generic type with automatic infer

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let say I want to create a "feature-config", which has the following type:

```
type FeatureConfig = {
   isActivated: boolean;
   childs?: {
      [key: string]: FeatureConfig;
   }
}

const config : FeatureConfig = {
   isActivated: true,
   childs: {
      bar: {
         isActivated: true,
         childs: {
            foo: {
              isActivated: true
            }
         }
      },
      foo: {
         isActivated: false,
         childs: {
            bar: {
              isActivated: true
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

All fine and typed-checked this far. Now I want to create a "build"-function which takes a `Config` and returns a "feature-tree" which I can check if a certain feature is activated. My goal with the function is to have the following syntax/functionality:

```
/// How should the types of this function look like??
const createFeatureChecker = (config: FeatureConfig) => {
   //...implementation
}

const featureChecker = createFeatureChecker(config);

featureChecker.bar.foo.isActivated // true
featureChecker.foo.isActivated // false
featureChecker.foo.bar.isActivated // false (since featureChecker.foo.isActivated is false)
```

I have no problems implementing the function logic in plain old javascript, but I'm struggling to type `createFeatureChecker` in a way so that I can use the `featureChecker` in a type-safe way.

Any ideas on how to solve my issue?

Comment: do you return another object of type `FeatureConfig` in your function? In that case I would add the return type to the function `createFeatureChecker = (config: FeatureConfig) : FeatureConfig => {...}`

Comment: No, I'm returning an object which takes the `FeatureConfig` and creates another object with *almost* the same structure (note that the `childs`-entries are removed)

Comment: Just a linguistic note: the plural of "child" is "children".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `as const` declaring `config` or pass it as an object literal.

```
const config = {
   isActivated: true,
   childs: {
      bar: {
         isActivated: true,
         childs: {
            foo: {
              isActivated: true
            }
         }
      },
      foo: {
         isActivated: false,
         childs: {
            bar: {
              isActivated: true
            }
         }
      }
   }
} as const
```

A typed `createFeatureFunction` would look like this:

```
type Expand<T> = T extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never

type CreateFeatureChecker<T extends FeatureConfig, Activated extends boolean = true> = {
    isActivated: Activated extends true ? T["isActivated"] : false
} & {
    -readonly [K in keyof (T["childs"])]: 
      (T["isActivated"] extends false ? false : Activated extends false ? false : true) extends infer A extends boolean
        ? T["childs"][K] extends { isActivated: infer B extends boolean } 
            ? T["childs"][K] extends { childs: infer C extends {
                [key: string]: FeatureConfig;
              }} 
                ? Expand<CreateFeatureChecker<{ isActivated: B, childs: C }, A>>
                : Expand<CreateFeatureChecker<{ isActivated: B }, A>>
            : never
        : never
}

const createFeatureChecker = <T extends FeatureConfig>(config: T): Expand<CreateFeatureChecker<T>> => {
   return {} as any
}
```

Some tests so see if it's working:

```
const featureChecker = createFeatureChecker(config);

const a = featureChecker.bar.foo.isActivated // true
const b = featureChecker.foo.isActivated // false
const c = featureChecker.foo.bar.isActivated // false
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=56&ssc=54&pln=51&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAYhCGwCuAnCBhA9gOwGYEsBzKAXigG8AoKG-AZwEEBjYfAN0QgBMAuKAI0yYANgmwBuajSYALfMK50A-Hyo11UANoBrCCD51gKfNkIBdPnESoMOAoUnqAvpReUmOQ1A94ipClJQ9MysHMDcfEZIEAA0gbLyiqqB6vzwKMkaWcEs7Jy8UFGxKVkJCnSZWVW4QpVVVTmh%20ZEo0SX1LvU0nVlOcdW1AV1BjLlhEVC48MJ0xcNlSUPDNGkZS8u0o03hBUXtVT0d7YcuTlDwdN6ewJSUoJBQAKIAHmDw2FwAPAAqAHz%203ygEGe4Q%20lxMuAgKCgAHkoEoKFoANJBbBQXQgTC4WEWWGaJFmKBnPjYCBsKG3e7QdBoThWZBodAyCBMXQoH5AkEQMGwBAM2y%20QgxKAhPI7TmgxQCISid7%20Ir-MhqdSNMUTUXjLgS7lSorwqDfTQAIlVmqNhL4UxmEFcUAAZOsoABaWlcHDCEDI1HovRYqAACkNRoWdHNAEpce1A8bTflzdqeVbZvqk9A%20Br8gmpamU9Nky1omGs%20C8FCRcXpSIxPt9UGQ%20b8YTgZLLuQRhmdnwIWWAEIVwRVuVnGsaBF1uTlBsEittkNd0vQ9Azkf1HR6AxGEzmSx8mxYQWODYaJzDo%20jp6vd5fGl8iD0vfM1lQz5t2OdqA94VzqBLvoi36-CuVR8C8bwfJ8N50rujKPmyL7tmMzQfkSwoMABQFQCSZIUl0WHkigri3D4XhMLS4T3jBLJsv4HLNjqlwUQK9i-P6Pj2Hw3xhiBl7gZB5HQRgsHPn8ir-MqUBoAyaLkGcFznNgICEe41yTAJTJUWWZCkbejHqU%20KCsXYRBhpIAD0pkaAAekoREqfA-iQtYlH6QAdKsLk1JgLlvtwUDmYUrQ2sRwACA5alCSgHlCN5Wxqlq-mpsp2AkWFTmCRpkWeW56QxR2vkJXmEBAA)

Comment: Wow that's some amazing TypeScript-skills! Didn't realize you could even type all the way so that `isActivated` is type-safe according to the function 

Thanks for the solution 